# Arara rule for automatic compilation of all files in a directory tree

Tags: loops, arara

I am currently using `arara` to give compilation rules for my `.tex` files. 
I have a lot of `tikz/pgfplots` made files which share common settings hosted in a `header` file, so that I can easily modify a setting, then recompile everything using a for loop e.g.

```
@FOR /R "rootdir" %%G in (.) DO (
@ Pushd %%G
@ for %%x in (*.tex) do arara "%%x"
@ Popd )
@pause
```

as I am on a windows machine.

However, this starts/stops `arara` a big bunch of times and throws very ugly logging to the terminal. 
So is there a rule or can one be written so that `arara` is only started once and compiles all files in a specified directory tree.

Comment: I've heard rumors that file globbing will be part of the next version ;)

Comment: @TeXnician Hmmm, sweet ! Any ideas on the release date ?

Comment: Well, it's expected to be released somewhen next year, so probably not the best alternive for you. But what already works is using the `listFilesByExtension` function in a custom rule.

Comment: @TeXnician you mean something like 
`% arara: ListFilesByExtensions(toFile('/directorypath'),'tex', true);` ?

Comment: No, you have to write a small rule that does (in MVEL, so that arara will process it) something like a for loop over the result of `listFilesByExtension` and returns something like `getCommand('command', loopvariable)`. But I'm short of time right now, so let's hope Paulo will see your question (and canonically answer) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as easy<sup>1</sup> as writing an own rule using `listFilesByExtensions` (save this as `all.yaml` next to your files):

```
!config
identifier: all
name: All TeX files
commands:
- name: All
  command: >
    @{
        a = [];
        foreach(ref : listFilesByExtensions(".", ["tex"], true)) {
          a.add(getCommandWithWorkingDirectory(ref.parent, [command, ref.name]));
        }
        return a;
    }
arguments:
- identifier: command
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.command
    }
  default: pdflatex
```

Then write an `arararc.yaml` like

```
!config
paths:
- ./
```

Your `header.tex` will then contain `% arara: all` and all TeX files within the directory tree will be compiled (sequentially). Please note that if you actually have your `header.tex` called `header.tex` it will be compiled as well. You could e.g. rename it to `header.ltx` to avoid it.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Actually, the first draft of this rule had to be revised. Thanks to Paulo Cereda for providing [an updated rule](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52426876#52426876).</sub>

Comment: I just tested your solution (I could not this week-end). I created the `all.yaml` and `arararc.yaml` files in the root image folder of my main document. My `header.tex` is not a standalone file, so I never do something like `arara header.tex`. It is a file that is called with an `\input{header}` in each `tikz/pgfplots` graph. To apply what you propose, I created an `allcompile.tex` file so that I can call it with `arara`. I actually says that it compiles successfully but with a ridiculously small amount of time. Do you know why ? Is there a way to see what file is actually being compiled ?

Comment: Already tried the `-v` option but it actually gave not much output. The `allcompile.tex` is in the root image folder and most tex files are contained in sub-folders. Is the `listFilesByExtensions` search recursive ?

Comment: Yep in my case recursive search is fine as all tex files in the tree are graphs. However, the compilation fails, as the working directory is always the root one while it should be the folder containing the actual tex of the graph, hence the `@ Pushd / @Popd` of my original script.

Comment: Well, I just noticed that I do not know enough about Windows bash to see these details. Actually, dealing with working directories is hard. Arara v5 will probably get working directory support but it will not support multiple working directories in one run for several reasons. I will try whether I can come up with a truly recursive logic.

Comment: Thanks for the update, though it does not seem to work. Compilation starts but not in the right directory. Is there a way to print the current value of a variable to the terminal ? I do not know much about yaml. I tried to add something like `print path;`  in the rule but it throws an error.

Comment: Run with `--dry-run` so we can see the working directory after the `@` symbol (if applicable).

Comment: @PauloCereda, thanks for the tip. The command built by `arara` looks like `pdflatex .\image-src\image.tex`. So basically it fails because it is not working in the right folder.  In fact, in the `.tex` file I have `pgfplots` calls that try to read data files in the `image-src` folder, so there should be a current directory change before each `pdflatex call`.

Comment: @TeXnician Just tried that, but it does not work either. I get a `[Error: ref.toString().split("\\"): Unexpected internal error near index 1` message. 
I just checked and there are system independent commands for path splitting in java, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8075373/9576551 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099859/how-to-split-a-path-platform-independent, but I could not make them work.

Comment: @TeXnician, Man that works ! Awesome ! I still have two remarks though. Sorry if they seem dumb, I am not familiar with java and even less with arara custom rules. 
Is it possible to display the currently being compiled .tex file instead of 'all'. Also, how can I pass options to `pdflatex`, in the `all.yaml` ?

Comment: @BambOo Unfortunately, the first point is impossible (from my knowledge) because they are within the same task. But for the second one you could try to pass something with options to the command parameter (it should accept `command: "pdflatex -option -option"`).