# Tikz with Standalone: One PDF for each side

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, standalone

Writting my bachelor thesis (unfortunatelly we are told to use MS Word) I am using Tikz for creating my figures. As I have several tikz-files I am using the standalone package to create a .pdf for each file.

But, when I now change for exmaple the font-size or the font-style I have to recompile every picture manually.

I kow you can compile more than one tikz-file inside the standalone, doing so results in 10 pages with one figure on each. The problem is that they are stored in one pdf-file.

Is there the possibility that the standalone can create a seperate file for each fiure? More, it would be great If I can set the name for those files to recognize them later on.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node{Picture 1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ## here I want to break the file to create seperate file with name=picture 2
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node{Picture 2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Picture:

[image]

## EDIT

After implementing the solution from Ross which seems to do what I intended to do occur in erros:

```
\documentclass[tikz, multi=true]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{importantFigure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node{Picture 1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\tikzsetnextfilename{anotherimportantFigure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node{Picture 2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My errors are:

[image]

However the pictures are printed and stored in one file each. But rerun the code results still in the error and the pictures are not updated.

Comment: You can externalise each of the pictures, like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1475

Comment: @Ross doing so result in an error I cannot resolve, however the pictures are printed, I will cahnge my original post

Comment: Also, \includegraphics has an undocumented option [page=..], so you really don't need to use multiple files.

Comment: You need to use `article` class, not `standalone`. Compile with `--shell-escape` enabled. Your MWE works for me with this change.

Comment: hm... changing to article results in one pdf with the nodes are on one huge page, not two seperate and tight crop files

Answer (score 3):

For my thesis I used the following procedure :

1. Create a `header_fig.tex` file containing all packages e.g. `\usepackage{...}` or libraries `\usetikzlibrary{...}` required for my pictures or settings e.g. `\tikzset{...}` or `\pgfplotsset{}`
2. Create one or more tikz pictures in separate `.tikz` files with the following format

```
\documentclasse[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\import{absolute/path/to/the/header_fig/file} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         <All of your favorite tikz code>
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `import` package avoids relative paths if you have a complex directory tree for all of your thesis pictures

3. If you want to modify global settings, just change them in the `header_fig` file
4. If you want to recompile all your pictures use a system `for-loop` or an `arara` call see [Arara rule for automatic compilation of all files in a directory tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511439/arara-rule-for-automatic-compilation-of-all-files-in-a-directory-tree) for instance.

This procedure allows to have separate `.tikz` and therefore `.pdf` files yet with global settings for all of your pictures. And I you want to speed up compilation, you can still add very specific libraries in the preamble of the relevant pictures.

Comment: thank you I will test it